# Working out resistance for unknown BJT circuit

Tags: dc, bjt

First of all, excuse me if this question is trivial or common, but I'm trying to essentially self-teach for an upcoming Analog Design exam, so I'm going through older problems that the professor had handed out.

There's a problem that reads: "The voltage sources in the schematic below are +10V and -10V. Explain the use of the circuit and work out the values for resistors \$R_1,R_2,R_3.\$ so that \$V_o = -6.5 V\$"

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKW03C.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've worked out a few things first. Assuming that the transistor is properly biased, then the voltage at the base node has to be \$-V + 0.7 = -9.3 V\$. With that, and the knowledge of the output voltage, all the voltage drops across the circuit are known. I've also noticed that \$R_3\$ acts as a voltage divider

I've tried multiple methods to derive some relationship that links the three resistors, but I'm unsure if my steps are correct. The first I tried was to apply KCL to the circuit, however I end up with a lot of unknown currents, and since the circuit doesn't have an emitter resistor, I can't simplify by letting \$R_e = 10R_2\$ so that \$I_b = 0\$.

I then thought about using a Thevenin equivalent for \$R_1,R_2\$, with \$V_o\$ as a 'source' since it's known, but that breaks the feedback loop that leads to the \$R_1,R_3\$ junction.

Can you provide any hints on how to approach this? I don't want a solution, I just want to understand how to approach it. Thank you.

Comment: To get anything like an accurate answer, you need to consider the beta of the transistor. You could also assume infinite beta and get a ballpark sort of correct-ish answer. Work backwards from the collector current needed to get the current in R3 to produce the output voltage required.

Comment: There are an infinite number of solutions without some other spec given such, as Iq, ,Rc  and hFE must be known. Then making some assumptions, it is possible. But Vbe=0.6 is more likely

Comment: Tony is quite correct also. Your problem is underdefined. For instance, if R2 is zero ohms then the transistor plays no part hence it can be removed leaving R1 and R3 to set the voltage at the output node. Quite simply, with R2 at zero, R3 needs to be 4.71428 times bigger than R1 and that works out just fine.

Comment: @Andy This is the only data that has been provided with the problem, unfortunately. No beta value, too. Judging by previous problems, I believe that once you have a working relationship between the resistors, you can choose one of them arbitrarily.
So far, Vbe has been given as 0.7 volts, so I guess it applies here, too.

Comment: If what made you assume Vbe is 0.7 volts is based on unrelated questions then it's a very poor exam problem. 0.7 volts is a ballpark figure and it may be lower or higher and, how far do you wish to go with this i.e. do you take into account temperature effects. Also, what model of transistor are you assuming. These are all unknowns to me and possibly to you.

Comment: I meant that it's what the professor uses in his material, and what was used in the previous course as de facto. He usually doesn't take temps into account to simplify problems, too. I agree that the problem is too vague, but I'm still struggling to at least understand what the circuit does. For starters, I haven't seen this configuration before -- specifically the voltage being divided before it reaches R1 and the collector. The question also asks about what the circuit does, could you provide some insight on that so I can study it? Thank you for your time.

Comment: user3115020, in general, there are two basic methods for stabilizingthe DC bias point with the aim to be somewhat independent on Vbe as well as the factor B=Ic/Ib. One method is to use an emitter resistor (I-controlled voltage feedback) and the other method is as shown: Voltage controlled current feedback. It is the main purpose of negative feedback to reduce the sensitivity of the whole circuit to (often uncertain) properties of the active device.

Comment: Useful search term : Vbe multiplier. Note : you can get a correct answer to the stated question by setting R2=0, turning Q1 off, and setting the potential divider R1,R3 to the required voltage! I dare you...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I'm now on the right path, as I almost reached the conclusion that this is a Vbe multiplier -- without knowing it. I replaced R1,R2 with their Thevenin equivalent, using Vo - Vee = 3.5 as a 'source' voltage, so the voltage drop across the load resistor (R2) was 0.7, which seems to coincide with the Thevenin voltage. Solving the voltage divider, [Vth = (R1/R1+R2)*Vce] gives me a relationship of R1 = 4*R2.

Comment: Vo is not a voltage source! , rather it's a current sink with high impedance collector, so it is Not a ratio voltage multiplier (unless R2=0)

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f23ZdR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There is also a solution when R2=0 as pointed out in comments.

Please understand , this is not a voltage multiplier but rather a feedback biased current sink, so that hFE and Rc make all the difference.

However this is not the normal application for this circuit which would be an AC amplifier with high open loop gain , DC biased at mid-scale then closed loop AC gain is reduced by Rcb.

[here R1=R2](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0YzCsICMA2SiDMiwA5nrzgEzYCcIyEiCc6AUAO4iEAsEz2I6%20I74tATp26JmzJqySjwTWDAHiIhHAqHJpS2bQAuTbByUcuag9MQgAtIUgkwzLNkJxEesOhKEoFEhVZxm6ODAWZSowBlVOOA8jJhYkWgBzTmwxGPQUzmQOCDCAJRVeETFeHJ5KUpzIOHkY3hjERA8IEkCwgHlMjkR3HhQkHpzafO7oqMlUsdKJcyxpSurGeql6nsJw4PGVEzXGDYDo7n2%20XYkTEZls9Ykj86OwxeFGiKLjlReNhqbaAAdnp4%20nmZBr9zmdVnA1EDXqCIf1Rl8HsY4vh9HF7s8eii4XxfljbllYmIoeiNts9Bd4icIEc9sJaAB7EAcZBiNgBImVWQkADsyAhjlMtHSnFM5RgIAAQgBTLQAQwA9AALABiAFFaEA) with Vc=-6.5V

(edit to add details and match RefDes)

Comment: That 3.1V appears... excessive :-)

Comment: So it was ... oops